# Is there any way to store the index of a network file system (SMB 2.0) on the server, so that my users don't have to manually set up the index?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, server-message-block, indexing, full-text-search

I apologize if this is in the wrong place, but I believe it is sufficiently server related. Also, just as a disclaimer: I'm not the server guy! I'm just trying to find out information.

I have several GB of PDF documents that I need to provide to my users, but they need to be able to search through all of them. On my local computer, Windows does a great job of indexing the contents of these documents. I can generally find the document I'm looking for within seconds.

I want to provide these documents on our institution's NFS, which is SMB 2.0 (Windows Server 2008R2).

Is there any way that I can index the documents at the server level, so that for the purposes of searching, I don't have to instruct each user to set up indexing on the share? Or is there no other way, indices are always stored locally, and I'll just have to provide these instructions to my users?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Windows Search Service, which is an additional service of the File Services Role.

Answer (score 1):

Windows search on the client can use the index created from search on the server. 
For pdfs you will need a pdf ifilter.
Here is the kb article about how to install the indexing service on the server

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954822/

You could also take a look at MS Search Server Express.